# Why does webSocketTask.receive never complete and how do I force completion in my Swift app?

Tags: swift, nwpathmonitor, urlsessionwebsockettask

I have a Swift app that uses a web socket to download stock price information from a public API. I send a message through the socket to subscribe to various stock price changes then wait for a continuous stream of messages to be received but when I turn off wifi the call to the message receive function, webSocketTask.receive, never returns. How can I force abort of the message receive function so that I alert the user that the network connection has been lost.

Here is my `NetworkServices` class;

```
import UIKit
import Network

protocol NetworkServicesDelegate: AnyObject {
    func sendStockInfo(stocksInfo: [String: StockInfo])
}

final class NetworkServices: NSObject {
    
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkServices()
    
    var urlSession: URLSession?
    
    var webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask?
    
    var stocksInfo: [String: StockInfo] = [:]
    
    var socketResults: [String: [StockInfo]] = [:]
    
    weak var delegate: NetworkServicesDelegate?
    
    var timer: Timer?
    
    var stockSymbols: [String] = []
        
    private let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
    
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    
    public private(set) var isConnected: Bool = false
    
    public private(set) var connectionType: ConnectionType = .unknown
    
    enum ConnectionType {
        case wifi
        case cellular
        case wiredEthernet
        case unknown
    }
    
    public func startMonitoring() {
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            self.isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
            self.getConnectionType(path)
            print("DEBUG: isConnected = \(self.isConnected); connectionType = \(self.connectionType)")
            if self.isConnected == false {
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func stopMonitoring() {
        monitor.cancel()
    }
    
    private func getConnectionType(_ path: NWPath) {
        if path.usesInterfaceType(.wifi) {
            connectionType = .wifi
        } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.cellular) {
            connectionType = .cellular
        } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.wiredEthernet) {
            connectionType = .wiredEthernet
        } else {
            connectionType = .unknown
        }
    }
    
    func fetchStockInfo(symbols: [String], delegate: CompanyPriceListVC) {
        
        stockSymbols = symbols
        
        self.delegate = delegate
        
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        
        configuration.waitsForConnectivity = false
                        
        urlSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        
        webSocketTask = urlSession?.webSocketTask(with: FINNHUB_SOCKET_STOCK_INFO_URL!)
        
        webSocketTask?.delegate = self
                
        webSocketTask!.resume()
        
        for symbol in symbols {
            
            let string = FINNHUB_SOCKET_MESSAGE_STRING + symbol + "\"}"
            
            let message = URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string(string)
            
            if isConnected {
                
                webSocketTask!.send(message) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("DEBUG: Error sending message: \(error)")
                    }
                    
                    self.receiveMessage()
                    
                }
            } else {
                
                // Post notification to view controllers that connection has been lost
                let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: isNotConnectedNotificationKey)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name, object: nil)
                
                // try to re-connect
                // successful re-connect?
                // No, keep trying. Yes, call send message method again
            }
        }
    }
            
    private func receiveMessage() {
        
        if isConnected {
            
            self.webSocketTask?.receive { result in
                
                print("DEBUG: Inside closure.")
                
                switch result {
                
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("DEBUG: Error receiving message: \(error.localizedDescription)")

                case .success(.string(let jsonData)):

                    guard let stockData = jsonData.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
                    
                    self.socketResults = [:]
                    self.stocksInfo = [:]
                    
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    do {
                        let socketData = try decoder.decode(SocketData.self, from: stockData)
                        guard let stockInfoData = socketData.data else { return }
                        for stockInfo in stockInfoData {
                            let symbol = stockInfo.symbol
                            if self.socketResults[symbol] == nil {
                                self.socketResults[symbol] = [StockInfo]()
                            }
                            self.socketResults[symbol]?.append(stockInfo)
                        }
                        
                        for (symbol, stocks) in self.socketResults {
                            for item in stocks {
                                if self.stocksInfo[symbol] == nil {
                                    self.stocksInfo[symbol] = item
                                } else if item.timestamp > self.stocksInfo[symbol]!.timestamp {
                                    self.stocksInfo[symbol] = item
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        self.delegate?.sendStockInfo(stocksInfo: self.stocksInfo)
                        
                        self.receiveMessage()
                        
                    } catch {
                        print("DEBUG: Error converting JSON: \(error)")
                    }
                    
                default:
                    print("DEBUG: default")
                }
            }
            print("DEBUG: Got here 1")
            
        } else {
            print("DEBUG: Got here 2")
            // Post notification to view controllers that connection has been lost
            let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: isNotConnectedNotificationKey)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name, object: nil)

            // try to re-connect.
            // successful reconnect?
            // No, keep trying. Yes, call receive message method again.
        }
    }

    func closeWebSocketConnection() {
        webSocketTask?.cancel(with: .goingAway, reason: nil)
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            print("DEBUG: didCompleteWithError called: error = \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    
    func fetchCompanyInfo(symbol: String, completion: @escaping (CompanyInfo?, UIImage?)->()) {
        
        let urlString = FINNHUB_HTTP_COMPANY_INFO_URL_STRING + symbol + "&token=" + FINNHUB_API_TOKEN
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching company info: \(error)")
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            do {
                let companyInfo = try decoder.decode(CompanyInfo.self, from: data)
                
                guard let logoURL = URL(string: companyInfo.logo) else { return }
                
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: logoURL) { data, response, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error fetching logo image: \(error)")
                    }
                    guard let data = data else { return }
                    
                    guard let logoImage = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
                    
                    completion(companyInfo, logoImage)
                    
                }
                task.resume()
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
                completion(nil, nil)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

extension NetworkServices: URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionWebSocketDelegate, URLSessionDelegate {
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, taskIsWaitingForConnectivity task: URLSessionTask) {
        print("DEBUG: inside taskIsWaitingForConnectivity")
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: Error?) {
        print("DEBUG: didBecomeInvalidWithError: error = \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?) {

        let reasonString: String
        if let reason = reason, let string = String(data: reason, encoding: .utf8) {
            reasonString = string
        } else {
            reasonString = ""
        }

        print("DEBUG: didCloseWith called: close code is \(closeCode), reason is \(String(describing: reasonString))")
    }

    func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
        print("DEBUG: urlSessionDidFinishEvents called")
    }
}
```

I have tried placing code in the pathUpdateHandler closure to cancel the task on the task object and finish current tasks and cancel on the URLSession object but neither works.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to post a notification when path.status == .satisfied. The notification goes to the custom UIViewController class which then calls the FetchStockInfo(symbols:delegate) method.